# Purpose of declaring variable without assigning value?

Tags: kentico

What is the purpose of declaring a variable without assigning a value to it? For example, I'm looking at the following code in a Text/XML transformation:

```
{%
    str1;
    bool1;
    bool2 = false;

    if (str1 != "something specific" && str1 != "") {
        bool1 = false;
        bool2 = true;
    }

    str1 = SomeFieldFromDataSource;

    return "";
#%}

{% if (bool1 != false) { return "<div>"; } #%}

{% if (bool2) { return "</div><div>"; } #%}

<div>Some content...</div>
```

What are the first two variable declarations doing? Are they just setting those variables to some default value? Without declaring a type somehow, how would Kentico know what value to use (unless it uses a single default value for everything)? Or, are the first two declarations unnecessary?

I've searched the internet, but I'm not seeing much out there on variable declaration, other than it shouldn't be necessary unless you're assigning a value. However, I'm reluctant to start deleting portions of code since I'm pretty new to Kentico and transformation syntax.

**EDIT**
To enhance my understanding of unassigned variables, I performed the following test in a transformation, with the result of each conditional expression shown in the comments to the right.

```
{% b; s; %} <!-- Evaluation of the following expressions is the same with or without this line. -->

{% if (b == true) { return "<div>b is true</div>" } #%}           <!-- false -->
{% if (b == false) { return "<div>b is false</div>" } #%}         <!-- false -->
{% if (b == null) { return "<div>b is null</div>" } #%}           <!-- true -->
{% if (b != true) { return "<div>b is not true</div>" } #%}       <!-- true -->
{% if (b != false) { return "<div>b is not false</div>" } #%}     <!-- true -->
{% if (b != null) { return "<div>b is not null</div>" } #%}       <!-- false -->

{% if (s == "") { return "<div>s is empty string</div>" } #%}     <!-- true -->
{% if (s == null) { return "<div>s is null</div>" } #%}           <!-- true -->
{% if (s != "") { return "<div>s is not empty string</div>" } #%} <!-- false -->
{% if (s != null) { return "<div>s is not null</div>" } #%}       <!-- false -->
```

To summarize, an unassigned variable `== null`, `!= true`, `!= false`, `== ""`. The only one of these that may be surprising is the last one, `== ""`. However, [the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/macro-expressions/macro-syntax#Macrosyntax-Operators) does state such:

> Empty strings are equal to null

Answer (score 1):

There is no real purpose aside from inheriting the datatype of the data assigned to it.  Very similar to how JavaScript works.  If you declare a variable without a value, it assumes an object.  If you assign a string, it will be a string.  If you assign an integer it assumes an integer.  So with this case, maybe the object could be an integer or a string.  Either way a value should be given when it's declared just for good coding and reading ease.

If this is code in production, I'd be sure to optimize it quite a bit.  But not knowing the full context of the code or if there is other code in that transformation, I'd have a hard time providing a valid example.

**Update**

Based on your updated code, it appears the code will only output `<div>Some content...</div>`

Since this code is executed each time a new item is rendered, it will not keep "global" values in place like JS might do.  You will have to assign the values to `str1` and `str2` each time and then perform some logical checking.

Comment: I've update the question with the full code (simplified). Any further insights would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that line `str1 = SomeFieldFromDataSource;` really does not have an effect, because that assigned value is not remembered when the transformation is executed for the next item, right? So if `str1` is not assigned before the first conditional, does `str1 != ""` evaluate to `true` or `false` (or `null`)? Similarly, for an unassigned `bool1`, which is true, `bool1 == true` or `bool1 == false` or `bool1 != true && bool1 != false`?

Comment: Where in the Kentico documentation is the treatment of unassigned variables specified? I couldn't find much.

Comment: Correct @neizan.  Since `str1` is not assigned before it is evaluated it is a null value so it will never set the boolean values. `bool1` would evaluate as null while `bool2` would evaluate as false.  There is nothing specific about unassigned variables, but it does state when the system resolves a macro expression, the result is an object.  https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/macro-syntax#Macrosyntax-Valuesandobjects

Comment: I've been doing some more testing on this code, and the transformation does remember the `str1` value from the previous iteration. Any thoughts why that might be? I may be getting into "new question territory" here...

Comment: I would not count on it being consistent as technically it shouldn't remember it.  You're better off building a custom transformation method and expose that as a macro method too.

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/adding-custom-methods-to-transformations

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it's safe to omit the declarations. I think the author of the code was just afraid that initializing the variables in the scope of the condition wouldn't set them globally if they weren't declared first. That's not the case.

But there's something else in the code that caught my attention. It's the `return ""` which may indicate this piece of code is doing some preliminary calculations whose output may be used later in the code. Don't forget it's possible to separate macro blocks like this:

```
// returns 2
{% return x + 2; %}

{% x = 1; %}

// returns 3
{% return x + 2; %}
```

Or like it's described in the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/macro-syntax#Macrosyntax-Conditionalstatements):

```
// Displays a message including the current date if the year is 2014 or more
{% date = CurrentDateTime; if (date.Year > 2013) { %}
The current date is: {% date %}. The registration period has ended.
{% } %}
```

So I would definitely look for any further usage of all the variables in the mentioned code.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code (simplified). Any further insights would be helpful. Specifically, it seems the author of this code expects the variables to maintain their values across iterations of the transformation. That is, if multiple objects have the transformation applied to them, then is it expected that `str1` will have a value at the start of second iteration? It seems it must work like that, but confirmation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

In Kentico's K#, all items are stored as an "object" more or less, not strongly typed, and then i believe it takes care of how it handles it through getting that object's type.

Where is this same code from? It may be just showing an example of how to do stuff.  You should be fine removing what you don't need and writing your own.

Comment: This is code from a website I'm working on...I just changed variable names. So those two variable "declarations" are there in the website, but I'm reluctant to remove them without knowing exactly what's going on.